# Why is the value attribute excluded when making a drop-down menu's answer tag?

Tags: html, forms

I'm learning web development for fun.

Now I am making a drop-down menu that asks security questions. I learned how to create one from a tutorial online. What I'm still confused about is why the value attribute is excluded for the answer's input tag. I thought it would be needed to send the answer to the server? Does the name attribute allow the answer to be sent?

My code is below.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <label for="question">Security question</label>
    <select name="question" id="question">
        <option value="q1">What is your favorite Pokemon?</option>
        <option value="q2">What is your favorite book?</option>
        <option value="q3">What is your city of birth?</option>

    </select>

    <br><br>
    <label for="answer">Security question answer:</label>
    <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Inputs of type "text" start out with a value of  "" (empty string) by default (unless you set a different [default with the `defaultValue` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp.)),  and then the value is whatever the user types.

You can set the value attribute your code to pre-fill the input, but it's generally not necessary. (You can also add a [`placeholder`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp), which shouldn't affect the `value`, and disappears when the user starts typing into that input since it only shows up when input is empty (`value = ""`).

And yes, the [`name`](https://html.com/attributes/input-name/) attribute is the main requirement for submitting to server. Inputs generally have a default value. Even for drop-downs, default value is usually the first option ("q1" in your case), unless the [`selected`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) attribute is added to one of the other `option`s.